# Synchronization of Data in iOS

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, smp

I am using SMP 2.3 to get the data from backend. Which is the best way to do this? -  NSOperation,GCD,Thread or simply writing everything in the main Thread.

Comment: Use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: What sense of "best"?

Comment: @StephenDarlington : By best, I mean an efficient way to synchronize the data. The data synchronization and loading should occur in the background so that the app does not freeze.

Comment: I would suggest to read the documentation of SMP and figure what "data synchronization" means in this context.

Comment: @abhhab I'm afraid your question has insufficient detail to say anything other than "not the main thread." And, for all I know, SMP could do its work on a background thread automatically.